# how to pass the data response twice into variables ? this code doesn't work to me

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to pass the data response into box and result,
box has the response after mounting but results showing undefined for some  reason

```
<script>
<!-- vueJs code -->
  export default{
    data(){ 
           return { 
           box:[],
           results:[],
           }      },
    mounted()
        {
         axios.get("/find")
        .then(response  => this.box = response.data)
        .then( response => this.results = response.data.slice(0,6);  
        }
            }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
axios.get("/find")
    .then(response  => {
        this.box = response.data
        this.results = response.data.slice(0,6)
    })
```

Comment: you are amazing thanks it worked. it was simple and I am really thankful :)